# Redirect output from erlang shell into a file

Tags: erlang

Is there a way to redirect data printed by `io:format()` from erlang shell into a file ? I know that I can open a file (IoDevice) and write data directly into it, but it requires code change and I don't want to do now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just run it with `erl -noinput -s module function -s init stop > file`.

Here's an example.

Erlang code:

```
-module(test).    
-compile(export_all).

function() ->
   io:fwrite("Hello world!~n").
```

In shell:

```
$ erlc test.erl 
$ erl -noinput -s test function -s init stop > test.txt
$ cat test.txt
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 14):

When a process calls `io:format()` and similar functions, the process sends io request messages to its group_leader process. So a simple hack is to open a file, and set it as the group_leader of the processes producing the output. Here is an example of redirecting the shell process's output to a file.

```
1> {ok, F} = file:open("z", [write]).
{ok,<0.36.0>}
2> group_leader(F, self()).
3> io:format("Where am I going to appear?~n").       
4>
```

This will only redirect the current shell process, so you will have to set the group_leader for all processes which you would like to redirect to the file.

The solution can be refined of course, for example by spawning a server process which proxies io request messages to rotated files, etc.

Comment: Nice hack! Could be quite helpful

Comment: This is ages after the answer. But how do I undo this? As in, after doing this, how can I again start getting messages back in the shell again?

Comment: To get it back to print back to the shell you can do erlang:group_leader(io).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the IODevice argument to io:fwrite/3 and let it have the atom value **standard_io** when you don't want it directed to some file. Otherwise give it the file.

See the "Standard Input/Output" section of the [io module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/io.html)'s documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can recompile your code with a parse transform, transforms calls like

```
io:format("~p~n", "Hello world!")
```

into calls like

```
io:format(whereis(my_output_file), "~p~n", "Hello world!")
```

Plus you need to add this into your start-up code, and you are done:

```
{ok, F} = file:open("file", [write]),
register(my_output_file, F),
```