# Erlang: How to write my outputs in a text file?

Tags: erlang

I need to write my outputs from shell into a text file to keeping some required records. Can anyone please tell me how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3718101/logging-libraries-for-erlang-otp/3720373#3720373)?

Comment: > file:write_file("test.txt", "Hello, world!").

Answer (score 28):

If you have the data you wish to store as a single term you can read how [here](http://trapexit.org/Save_Data_to_a_File). In the simplest case you can just do `file:write_file(Path, Data)`. If your data is more complex you may want to use `io_lib:fwrite/2` to format it in a more readable way. For example:

```
Data = [1,2,3,{car, "honda"}],
file:write_file("/tmp/foo", io_lib:fwrite("~p.\n", [Data])).
```

Answer (score 4):

[tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) command can capture shell output and save it to a file:

```
$ erl | tee output.txt
Eshell V5.8  (abort with ^G)
1> A = 5.
5
2> 5 + A.
10
3> ^Ca

$ cat output.txt 
Eshell V5.8  (abort with ^G)
1> 5
2> 10
3>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many possibilities. Here's the first one which came to my mind.

In Erlang, every process is part of a *group*. For each group, a process - named *group leader* gets all the output from the group-mates. The shell process is part of the group *init*. So, what you could do is to [change the *group leader*](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#group_leader-2) for the shell process by doing:

```
{ok, Log} = file:open("log", [write]),
erlang:group_leader(Log, self()).
```

You might want to create a dedicated process acting as group leader who manages the output in a more clever way. For example, it could wrap the file after a while or when the file reaches a certain size.

The problem with this approach is that you have to execute these lines any time you start your shell. Doing it by using the -s flag:

> erl -s shell_log

where shell_log is:

```
-module(shell_log).

-export([start/0]).

start() ->   
    {ok, Log} = file:open("log", [write]),
    erlang:group_leader(Log, self()).
```

won't work, because it's still too early (init is still in `{starting, started}`, as reported by `init:get_status()`).

In the same way, doing it by using the `.erlang` file in your HOME directory (whose lines are automatically executed every time you start a shell) will fail for a similar reason (init is still in the `{starting, applications_loaded}` state).

Not sure which is the best way to circumvent this problem. I'll think about it.

Finally, this question seems a duplicate of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2140604/redirect-output-from-erlang-shell-into-a-file).